# PerlApp-generated-exe can't Load packages

Tags: perl, eclipse-pdt, activeperl, perlapp

PerlApp generate perl script to executable. I get a problem using the PerlApp
 Here are the steps:

1. Generate a perl script (e.pl) with the following 2 lines
   require Date::Manip;
   require Date::Manip::DM6;
2. perlapp e.pl --add Date::Manip --add Date::Manip::DM6
3. e.exe generate the following errors:
   c:_test>e.exe
   ERROR LOADING MODULE: Date::Manip::DM6 at /Date/Manip.pm line 35.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add more than just Date::Manip::DM6:

```
perlapp --add Date::Manip::** e.pl
```

The wildcards indicate that all submodules in the Date::Manip namespace should be added, including some that are more than 1 level down. The error is because DM6 depends on these other submodules, some of which seem to be implicit.

Also you don't need to `require Date::Manip::DM6` as that is not how you're meant to use the module. Version 6 is used automatically depending on your version of perl, which gets included in your compiled exe.

Answer (score 1):

*Just in case you're suffering from an [`XY Problem`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem):*

Considering using [`pp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/pp) instead of [`PerlApp`](http://docs.activestate.com/pdk/6.0/PerlApp_overview.html).  The following works just fine:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Date::Manip;

print "Hello World\n";
```

And then packaging:

```
pp hello_date.pl
```

Comment: Thanks!. I had problem install PAR::Packer on my window 7 system. I run out of time on this topic. So, I pick the paid solution.